# Using 'raw' OpenGLES2.0-3.0 API in Qt

Tags: qt, opengl-es

I have the following situation.I have a renderer based on OpenGLES 2.0-3.0 APIs.I need to embed it into Qt based desktop widget app.I have read about Qt GL wrappers ,which is one way to use  GL ES API in Qt App.But in my case I cannot afford rewriting the whole engine rendering code to use Qt's GL wrappers not only because of the scope, but mostly because of portability issues.So I tried to include `GL/GLES3.0/gl3.h` headers which are exposed in Qt SDK. Doing this I am getting all sort of header collision errors, for  example like this one:

> D:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015\include\QtANGLE\GLES3\gl3.h:73: error: C2371:
>   'GLsizeiptr': redefinition; different basic types

So how can I use just raw OpenGL ES API in Qt?

For Desktop OpenGL I know I should build the SDK with desktop opengl flag on,and then use some GL loader lib like GLEW to init all the GL func pointers.Does it mean I must do something similar for GLES? For example ,building the SDK without ANGLE,then link with ANGLE lib explicitly?

I have asked this question also [on Qt's forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/77207/using-raw-opengles2-0-3-0-api-in-qt).Received no answer.

UPDATE:

I examined some Qt headers to see where the above mentioned collision happens.So Qt has `qopengl.h` header which declares GL functions and types.But it also has ANGLE's gl headers,which I try to include and which declare the same stuff.So this causes the collision.I don't understand why they allow both headers into the SDK.How to get rid of `qopengl.h` and run with ANGLE headers only?

Comment: Maybe don't include them in the same file? You can call `void myRenderFunction()` in `QOpenGLWidget::paintGL()`. The Qt-related code will include `MyRenderFunction.h` header that won't have any GL includes, so there will be no conflicts.

Comment: I removed all the Qt's headers which load GL functions,like   <QOpenGLFunctions> .It doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Some Qt headers may include them indirectly. There may also get in through precompiled headers or qt-moc generator.

Comment: @Velkan see my update

Comment: As I understand, Qt includes all gl that it can find, and then provides `QOpenGLFunctions_1_0`, `QOpenGLFunctions_3_0`, `QOpenGLFunctions_4_5_Core`, `QOpenGLFunctions_ES2` etc to access them (and to call things like `bool QOpenGLFunctions_4_5_Core::initializeOpenGLFunctions()` to see if they are accessible in the runtime). It doesn't try hard to avoid conflicts when user includes other GL headers. I was having a similar conflict that was resolved by including GL headers before the Qt headers. All I know that is these things are fragile.